# Volume of triangular bipyramid.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I am doing my yr 12 exams. 
I just wpuld like the simply know if my answers are correct or incorrect.

1. Volume of triangular bipyramid
   Triangular base is 24cm2
   Perpendicular height of each pyramid is 10cm
   What is the volume. 
   ANS: 1/2 x 24 x 10 = 120cm3
2. What is the linear function with a y-intercept of 5? 
   ANS: y = 5 + x

Comment: Your first answer should start with $\frac 2 3$ instead of $\frac 1 2$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipyramid#Volume).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The volume of an ordinary pyramid is $V=\frac{1}{3}Bh$, where $B$ is the area of the base and $h$ is the height. Both of these are given, so the volume of one pyramid is $V=\frac{1}{3}(24)(10)=\frac{24}{3}\times10=8\times10=80.$ Since a bipyramid is two of these oriented base-to-base, the final volume is twice this, or 160.
2. I feel this is a poorly worded question, because there is more than one linear function with a $y$-intercept of $5$. Even if there is only one, there are multiple ways to write a linear function. Your answer is correct, just know it is not the only one.